# CollectionView [__NSCFConstantString _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, string, multithreading, sigabrt

I find a signal SIGABRT thread when I run my App. Here is the error message :
    [__NSCFConstantString _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c20

The problem is coming from
     [[self myCollectionView]setDataSource:self]; 
because it disappear when I comment it.

On what I've understand, type of myCollectionView datasource and self are not the same. This is why I have my error.

Thanks for your help

Pierre

CalViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CalViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *myCollectionView;

@end
```

CalViewController.m

```
#import "CalViewController.h"

#import "CustomCell.h" 

@interface CalViewController ()
{
    NSArray *arrayOfImages;
    NSArray *arrayOfDescriptions;
}

@end

@implementation CalViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[[self myCollectionView]setDataSource:self];
[[self myCollectionView]setDelegate:self];

arrayOfImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"chibre.jpg",nil];
arrayOfDescriptions =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Test",nil];
}
- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 
return [arrayOfDescriptions count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell =  ([collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]);

    [[cell myImage]setImage:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    [[cell myDescriptionLabel]setText:[arrayOfDescriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSections:(UICollectionView *) collectionView
                                          {return 1;
                                          }


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `arrayOfImages` is an array of image names (strings), so `setImage` won't work with that. Instead of:

```
[[cell myImage]setImage:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
```

you probably intended:

```
[[cell myImage]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];
```

or, equivalently:

```
cell.myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:arrayOfImages[indexPath.item]];
```

You might even want to rename `arrayOfImages` to be `arrayOfImageNames` (or just `imageNames` or whatever) to eliminate this possible source of confusion.

(BTW, it was a good call not to put the actual images in the array. We should always create the image objects in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` on the basis of the image names in the array.)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `[[cell myImage]setImage:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];` with

```
NSString *imageName = [arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
[cell.myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

The problem is that right now you are trying to assign an `NSString` to something that should be a `UIImage`.